# How to listen to keydown event on angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, keyboard-events

I want to listen to keyboard event on the angular-material table to manipulate the selected row. I have tried with the directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[keyDownAction]'
})
export class KeyDownDirective {
    constructor() {
    }

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
handleClick(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
}

}
```

host listening:

```
  host: { '(keydown)': 'hotkeys($event)' },
```

and direct:

```
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i=index"
             [focus]="selectedRow==i"
             (click)="clickOnRow(row, $event, i)"
             (dblclick)="dblClickOnRow(row, $event, i)"
             (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"
             >
```

where click and dblclick works.

Do anybody know a workaround?

Comment: I am not sure is it what you want.
 https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14861.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very late answer but for future finders of this issue...

Anything that is not an `<input>` needs the `tabindex` attribute in order for the `keydown` event to fire. Any index number will do. Simply change your code to be...

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i=index"
         tabindex=0
         [focus]="selectedRow==i"
         (click)="clickOnRow(row, $event, i)"
         (dblclick)="dblClickOnRow(row, $event, i)"
         (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"
>
```